# What does phi component of a cylindrical coordinate signifies?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

So I have a point $(r, \phi, z)$ which I can express in the cartesian coordinate system as $(r cos \phi, r sin \phi, z)$. If I would convert the components of the vector (to cylindrical coordinates)
$
\begin{bmatrix}
r cos \phi \\
r sin \phi \\
z 
\end{bmatrix}
$
by multiplying with transformation matrix
$
\begin{bmatrix}
cos \phi & sin \phi & 0 \\
-sin \phi & cos \phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$ we get
$
\begin{bmatrix}
r \\
0 \\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$.
My question is why the $\phi$ component of result zero ? What does it ($\phi$ component) signify here in case of a point on a surface of cylinder ? I thought about this, and I think since the cylindrical coordinate system was made up by a radius and the rotation of point, direction of $\phi$ doesn't have any sense here hence it is zero here. Is this correct ? If so, is there any mathematical definition for this ?

Edit: I posted this question because I was trying to prove divergence theorem on a closed cylindrical surface ($\pi$/4 < $\phi$ < $\pi$/2; 0 < z < 1/2; $r=2$), I took a differential area on the side rectangles $drdz$, but could not figure direction of area in terms of vector component. Should it be $\hat{\phi}$ ($-\hat{\phi}$ for $\pi/4$) or 0 as we found for transformation matrix ? My intuition says it would be $\hat{\phi}$ but I can't explain the 0.

Comment: The greek letter $\theta$ is called theta, not phi

Answer (score 1):

In 3D space we may draw a line through the origin, and consider every 2D plane which contains that line. Every point $P$ in the space which lies away from the line belongs to exactly one such plane. To describe $P$ is cylindrical coordinates, we first give its 2D rectangular coordinates $r$ and $z$ in the plane which contains it. Then we specify the plane using an angle $\theta$.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for answering ! You might want to see the backstory I added in main question, cheers!